# my react-native app is showing error while fetching data from my server error : "type error :Network Request Failed "

Tags: react-native, ssl, https, fetch

its working fine in android emulator but not working in device.

componentDidMount() {

```
return fetch('http://ABCD.in/App/TermJSON.jsp')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);
    this.setState({
      dataSource: responseJson.feeList,
      isLoading: false
    }, function () { }
    );

  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    alert(error);
  })
```

}//compo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for android use `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

for newer android version it is disabled by default